# Add delay to on('data') execution in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function. Basically it searches data from database and does something with it. In this demo it just increases counter.

```
exports.fullThreads = function(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, (err, db) => {
      var fullThreads = db.collection('tmp_fullThreads'),
          threadPages = db.collection('tmp_threadPages').find();

      var counter = 0;

      threadPages.on('data', (doc) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
          counter++;
        }, 200)
      });

      threadPages.on('end', () => {
        console.log('end');
        console.log(counter);
      });

    });//connect
  });//promise
}//fullthreads
```

In this example I expected that it would call for data, wait 200ms, and then increase counter. Once it reaches the end, it would end. However it is different. `on('end')` is called before `on('data')` actually finished. I guess that is because it didn't return value immediately. So this `setTimeout` function is not a way to go. However I have a real problem here. This is simply way too fast and in real life code, this wouldn't increase counter, it would call foreign API which doesn't accept so many calls in so little time, so I wanted to make a delay between each call, how is this done properly?

Comment: Have you tried using the streams2 methods (e.g. `threadPages.read()` and the `'readable'` event) instead of using a `'data'` event handler? Otherwise, you should be able to manually `pause()` and `resume()` the stream as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my workaround:

```
  var threadPages = db.collection('tmp_threadPages').find();
  var delay = 0;

  function test(doc, delay){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(delay);
    }, delay)
  }

  threadPages.on('data', (doc) => {
    test(doc, delay);
    delay += 100;
  });
```

It works well if  you do not need to bind proper events to `on('end` method. Basically it increases delay per request, otherwise it would fire all of them at once. This makes code go slower and it wouldn't overkill API with too many requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

Then you would need some kind of queu
eg:

```
queuTasks = [];
queuTasks.push("Task1");
queuTasks.push("Task2");

function doTasks(){

   // Do your task
   if(queuTasks.length > 0){
       console.log(queuTasks[0]);
       queuTasks.splice(0,1); // Remove it from the queu
   }
   setTimeout(function(){ doTasks();}, 1000);
}
```

This is just some quick code i made, may not work out of the box. But think you get the idea.

I know this is not entirely what you were asking about